# How to set a variables in SecureWindow object in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

LWC replaces window object with SecureWindow, there is no much documentation about how to set variables in this object.

Can we set properties on SecureWindow?

Answer (score 2):

> [SecureWindow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.security_locker_global_access) : Secure wrapper for the window object, which
>   represents a window containing a DOM document. If a Lightning web
>   component and an Aura component belong to the same namespace, they
>   share the same SecureWindow instance.

It represents just the wrapper and returns the instance. It means that you should still call the **window object** by representation of `window` only. Its just that certain properties in `window` are unavailable because they are removed at the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) level. You can check which methods/properties are still available in [Locker API Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer)

However note that you can still create your own properties or methods on `window` object (which is SecureWindow instance).

```
window.myProp = 'Some sample string';   // property on window
window.myFunc = () => console.log('Logging some random text');    // function on window
```